# AppleLanguages gives me the locale too, what if I only want to know the language

Tags: iphone, localization

Example: en_GB is output, need en.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", currentLanguage);
```

Comment: It does not always work. zh_TW is completely different from zh_CN, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayOfSeperatedString = [currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
NSLog(@"%@", [arrayOfSeperatedString objectAtIndex:0]);
```

edit:

A better way would be:

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currentLanguage] autorelease]; //Sets the what laguage the language name and country name should be written in
NSString *displayNameString = [currentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:currentLocale]; //Sets what language you want written..

NSLog(@"The current language is: %@", displayNameString);
```

Now if the current language is french (fr_FR) this returns:

> ```
> The current language is: français (France)
> ```

If the current language is english (en_US) this returns

> ```
> The current language is: English (United States)
> ```

Now if you want to ommit the country name use `componentsSeperatedByString:@" ("` as described above..

Comment: Thanks ;) With the currentLanguages I can also select the object at index 0 and then I receive "en" instead of what I had before.